# chocolatey upgrade all -y command fails

Tags: chocolatey

I've been getting this error for a long time and can't update it.
Error Like for every package:

> You have flashplayeractivex v32.0.0.293 installed. 
>   Version 32.0.0.303 is available bflashplayeractivex not upgraded. An error occurred during installation:              Unable to read package from path 'autohotkey.portable\autohotkey.portable.nupkg'.

https://prnt.sc/qh9dj0

Answer (score 0):

Check and make sure autohotkey is installed correctly, as you can see only those packages that rely on autohotkey for the installation process failed.